# How do I allow a single table cell to expand in a fixed table layout?

Tags: css

I've got a fixed width table that has 3 columns. I want the first column to resize based on the text, the second column is fixed width, and the third column should take the remainder of the space and truncate any part that doesn't fit in the cell (text-overflow: ellipsis). The table is just the single row.

Here's a simplified version of my table...

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>250.9</td>
        <td> | </td>
        <td>This is really long and should be truncated</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

1st column is a decimal number from 1 to 250, single decimal precision.
2nd column is just a separator between the first and last column.
3rd column is a user-entered title that can be very long, though typically fits in the space provided.

Here is a Fiddle project that shows one of the things I've tried: http://jsfiddle.net/A4N2z/2/

I've also tried a set of floated divs, but the last div wraps to the next line if it doesn't fit: http://jsfiddle.net/5Epvw/1/

Since it's just a single row, it doesn't have to be a table if somebody knows of another approach. The goal is for the text to line up in a single row and be no wider than a certain width.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code block (you can change the width of the container as necessary)

```
<div id="container">
    <div class="nbr">1.2.3</div >
    <div class="sep"> | </div >
    <div class="title">This is a really long title</div >
</div>

#container
{
    width:500px;
}

#container div
{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: That doesn't seem to solve the problem. The 'title' gets pushed to a second line.

Answer (score 0):

In the end I used a table and truncated the title based on characters (best solution I could find). I used [Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/api/String/truncate) to do the actual truncation on the client because the value is dynamic and Sugar's truncate method is pretty smart about how it truncates the string.